# How to destroy a file?

Tags: file, filesystems, overwrite

How can I overwrite a file so that the new data won't just be allocated somewhere else and the old data deallocated but rather be certain that said data is actually overwritten?

lets assume I'm working with C on windows (even though a universal method will be preferred)